# unable to load nested data in MVC4 with relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This is the DataController Class:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult EmployeeRequests()
    {
        List<EmployeeRequests> CO = new List<EmployeeRequests>();
        using (EmployeeContext dc = new EmployeeContext())
        {
            //var cust = dc.Employees.OrderBy(a => a.EmpName).ToList();
            var cust = dc.Employees.OrderBy(a => a.EmpName).ToList();
            foreach (var i in cust)
            {
                var requests = dc.Requests.Where(a => a.EmployeeID.Equals(i.EmployeeID)).OrderBy(a => a.RequestDate).ToList();


                CO.Add(new EmployeeRequests
                {
                    Employee = i,
                    Requests = requests
                });
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = CO, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

Unable to load nested data in MVC4 with relationship once i remove relation between tables it executes .

I'm using 2 tables Employee and Requests.

Comment: Where is the Mapping?

Comment: Do you have some error?

Comment: No Errors without relationship i am able to load the data perfectly

Comment: or if i add any table to my EmployeeDataModel which has relationship with Employee table it doesnt load data. it gives me no data with just table headers